# Get All text between two strings

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get all texts between two strings

First str: `<p style="text-align: justify;">`

Second str:`</p>`

text like this:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">aaaaa</p><p style="text-align: justify;">ddddd</p><p style="text-align: justify;">bbbbb</p>
```

I want the output to be

```
aaaa
dddd
bbbbb
```

and so on

i tried this function, but no idea how to loop it..

```
Public Function GetClosedText(ByVal source As String, ByVal opener As String, ByVal closer As String) As String
Dim indexOfOpener = source.IndexOf(opener)
Dim result As String = ""
If indexOfOpener >= 0 Then ' default is -1 and indices start with 0
    indexOfOpener += opener.Length ' now look behind the opener
    Dim indexOfCloser = source.IndexOf(closer, indexOfOpener)
    If indexOfCloser >= 0 Then
        result = source.Substring(indexOfOpener, indexOfCloser - indexOfOpener)
    Else
        result = source.Substring(indexOfOpener) ' takes the rest behind the opener
    End If
End If
Return result
```

End Function

Comment: why not use regex ? much easier

Comment: Here's a regex pattern you can use: `/(\w+)(?=<)(?!>)/gm`

Comment: so you just want to find all the <p> tag and get the text for the tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex: `<p[^>]*>(?<TEXT>[^<]*)<\/p>`

`<p[^>]*>` Match the text inside the tag and the tag `<p >`

`(?<TEXT>[^<]*)` Find the string between the tags and name it group "TEXT"

`<\/p>` Match the escape tag `<\p>`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/taX7P4/1)

```
Dim input As String = "<p style=""text-align: justify;"">aaaaa</p><p style=""text-align: justify;"">ddddd</p><p style=""text-align: justify;"">bbbbb</p>"

For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(input, "<p[^>]*>(?<TEXT>[^<]*)<\/p>")
     Console.WriteLine(match.Groups("TEXT"))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find the text between `<p>` tags. The regex pattern you want should detect **words** between `>` and `<`. Hence, you can use this: `(\w+)(?=<)(?!>)`

**`?=`** means should be followed by this

**`?!`** means should be preceded by this

**`\w+`** means one or more letters between the two.

Here's an example code that prints each matched text to the `Console`:

```
  Dim pattern As String = "(\w+)(?=<)(?!>)"
  Dim input As String = "<p style=""text-align: justify;"">aaaaa</p><p style=""text-align: justify;"">ddddd</p><p style=""text-align: justify;"">bbbbb</p>"

  For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
     Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", 
                       m.Value, m.Index)
  Next
```

Comment: Not working.. 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' cannot be converted to 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match'. Also, what's "sentence"

Comment: Can you try now?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand string manipulation

```
        Dim xstr As String = "<p style=""text-align: justify;"">aaaaa</p><p style=""text-align: justify;"">ddddd</p><p style=""text-align: justify;"">bbbbb</p>"
        Dim temp As String = ""
        Dim String1 As String = "<p style=""text-align: justify;"">"
        Dim String2 As String = "</p>"
        Dim xlist As New List(Of String)
        Do
            xstr = Mid(xstr, InStr(xstr.ToLower, String1.ToLower) + String1.Length)
            xlist.Add(Mid(xstr, 1, InStr(xstr.ToLower, String2.ToLower) - 1))
            xstr = Mid(xstr, InStr(xstr.ToLower, String2.ToLower) + String2.Length)
        Loop Until InStr(xstr.ToLower, string1.ToLower) = 0
```

Comment: how to display the result?

Comment: they are in a list object xlist.items(index)xlist.count will give you the number of items in the list. first one always 0